# Convert multiple group of PNG files to multilayered ICO files

Tags: files, osx, rename, conversion, imagemagick

Let say I've many files named e.g.:

- FirstIcon_16.png
- FirstIcon_32.png
- FirstIcon_colored_16.png
- FirstIcon_colored_32.png
- SecondIcon_16.png
- SecondIcon_32.png
- SecondIcon_colored_16.png
- SecondIcon_colored_32.png

I want to convert those PNG images to **multi layered ICO** files at once. I can convert one set with same name to multi layered ICO with this command:`convert *.png -alpha on -set filename:fname %t %[filename:fname].ico`

So is there some way to create multiple ICO files at the same time fro. So output will be e.g.

- FirstIcon.ico
- FirstIcon_colored.ico
- SecondIcon.ico
- SecondIcon_colored.ico

What is proper way? To use somekind of for loop. or what?:

```
for f in *.png; do
  convert *.png -alpha on -set filename:fname %t %[filename:fname].ico
done
```

That for loop doesn't work ofc. But how I can do this kind task with bash? I'm not so familiar with bash commands so any help is very welcome.

Comment: If all your image groups look the same (same basic name in one group, all ending with `_16.png`, `_32.png`, ...), you can do something like `for f in *_16.png; do b=$(basename $f _16.png); convert $b*.png -alpha on -set filename:fname %t %[filename:fname].ico; done`.

Comment: Thanks ridgy! It seems to work in my solution pretty well! So this is great answer. If you want to submit this in answer I can mark it to correct.